# CkEditor is not destroying instance

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, ckeditor

I am using CkEditor to edit content and calling that page via ajax. It is working fine for first page load. But when I load another page, in console I see error that Instance is already exists. So tried to replace all textarea using `CKEDITOR.replaceAll();` in everypage. But Again I get same error. When I searched for this error. I came accross other stackoverflow question With answer

```
if(editor.instance(Instancename) {
    CKEDITOR.instances.textarea.destroy();
}
```

But I have multiple textarea,generated randomly so I can not use that code as I don't know `id` or `name` of textarea. Anyone have better suggesation what I should do to replace textarea to ckeditor?

Comment: a work around is to generate each with a random name

Comment: Generating with same calss per page and replacing by classname is better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `CKEDITOR.replaceAll()`

will create an instance but you are not reloading the page, so it will not destroy.

You have to distroy it manually.

But as you said you have multiple textarea generated randomly, you can use

`CKEDITOR.replaceAll('className');`

All you have to do is give classes to text-area (same class in onepage) and write this code right after you appending `html` to `div`.

And use `/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js`